# Desire2learn- How to view file access dates

Tags: desire2learn

I'm having some trouble configuring our Desire2Learn install. I'd like to be able to view all dates/times at which a file was accessed by a user. So far, I am only able to see if the file was opened, or not.

Any advice?

Thank you